# Why is wc -c printing spaces before the number?

Tags: macos, command-line, bash

command:

```
echo "test" | wc -c
```

results (7 leading spaces):

```
"       5"
```

I tested this on my linux box and I don't get the space in front of the five. is this a bug or expected behavior?

Answer (score 12):

This is by design. You can see how `wc` pads “tabs” by removing the `-c` so it drops the first number in alignment with where the others would be.

You can gobble up the white space if you need with another pipe, but you should plan on this if you’re scripting things on macOS and don’t drop a different `wc` command down. The options are endless

```
echo "test" | wc -c | xargs
echo "test" | wc -c | tr -d ' '
echo "test" | wc -c | sed 's/ //g'
echo $(echo "test" | wc -c)
```

Comment: @nohillside What happens when `echo "$(echo "test" | wc -c)"`?  Isn't it good practice to quote command substitution?

Comment: @fd0 All the examples will need adaptions when used in real scenarios. For the situation here `echo "$(echo `test' | wc -c)"` would do, or just the trust that `wc -c` will work as documented and always returns a number of spaces followed by a number.

Comment: @nohillside  OK, then there are exceptions to the rule. :-) Anyways, all the examples give the wrong character count because they include the newline character after the string "test" which gives you a count of five characters  instead of four.

Comment: @fd0 So does the question, actually. The problem here is more about the leading spaces than the count itself, at least I think it is. As for the quoting: it is more important in situations where whitespace is relevant, not in situations where you want to get rid of it.

Comment: `You can see how wc pads “tabs” by removing the -c so it drops the first number in alignment with where the others would be.` I can't really understand what you mean by this.

Comment: @ruohola if you just run `wc` it outputs values for lines, words, and characters. Like this: `echo 'foo\nbar baz' | wc` which produces 2 3 12 all spaced apart. That spacing still exists if you add `-c` or `-l` or `-w` to just get one values. Arguably it shouldn't do that, but that's how it works and changing it would probably break something.

Answer (score 2):

I find this solution to be more portable in various situations, since I really just want the number of "lines" more often than not.

`echo "test" | awk 'END{print NR}'` which returns `1`

This post has additional information on POSIX implementation https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/205910